# Объясните новичку почему в цикле While Update срабатывает только один раз а не проходится по циклу

Tags: php, update, while

```
    $db->Query("SELECT * FROM db_video_users WHERE parts>'0' ORDER BY id DESC");
  $tim = time();
while($datas = $db->FetchArray()){
  $id = $datas["id"];
  $db->Query("UPDATE db_video_users SET time_earn = '$tim', parts = parts-'1' WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

Comment: Результат не получен, коннекция занята и не может выполнить следующий запрос.

Comment: пытаюсь расшифровать то что Вы сказали) Результат то как раз получен, но цикл не повторяется

Comment: Вы выполнили первый запрос (до цикла). Он вернул результат. Вы его "выгребли" из соединения, выполнив FetchArray. Соединение освободилось и готово к работе. Затем выполнили второй запрос (в цикле на первом витке). Он вернул результат. Вы пытаетесь выполнить третий запрос (на втором витке цикла). Однако в соединении ещё лежит результат выполнения второго запроса. Поэтому соединение неспособно выполнить третий запрос - при этом результат второго запроса потеряется, а это недопустимо. Так что добавьте в цикл ещё и фетч.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за развернутый ответ. Я новичок и не совсем понимаю как и куда добавить именно..

Answer (score 3):

```
$db->Query("UPDATE db_video_users SET time_earn = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), parts = parts-'1' WHERE parts>'0'")
```

Не занимайтесь, пожалуйста, анонизмом.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в классе, реализующем метод `Query()`. Есть даже специальный [список граблей, на которые наступают начинающие писатели классов для работы с базой данных](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes). Конкретно эти лежат под номером 8.

Учитывая, что в этом классе цветут и пахнут грабли под номером 1 - SQL инъекция, то от него надо избавляться немедленно.

Если класс писали вы сами, то его надо переписать. Я могу с этим помочь. Если взяли где-то по случаю, то надо от него отказаться, и взять что-то нормальное. Лучше всего - чистый PDO и научиться сначала работать с ним.